# Can we get address of a variable in a C program using GDB?

Tags: linux, gdb

Actually, I was learning about the buffer overflow attack. So, can we figure out buffer address (I am using buffer variable in my program so that while writing in the buffer, I will make changes in the stack)?

Comment: Same question on stack overflow: [gdb - Find the exact address of variable Buf - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462915/find-the-exact-address-of-variable-buf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as your variable isn’t optimised away.

For example, using `ls` with debug symbols:

```
gdb ls
>>> break main
>>> run
>>> print argv
$1 = (char **) 0x7fffffffdd78
```

In this case, `argv` is a pointer itself. If you want the address of a non-pointer variable, or the address of a pointer, use `&` as you would in C; `gdb` will give you the address, as above, or tell you if the variable isn’t stored in memory:

```
>>> printf &argc
Address requested for identifier "argc" which is in register $rdi
```

On x86, the contents of `SP` will tell you where the stack is:

```
>>> i r sp
sp             0x7fffffffdc98      0x7fffffffdc98
```